# Enterprise Library Policy Injection Logging Managed Security Context Information in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, logging, enterprise-library, identity, policy-injection

I am using The Policy Injection Application Block to log methods that are called in my ASP.NET  application. I would like these log entries to include information like the current user identity, whether the user is authenticated and so forth. All of this information is provided by the `ManagedSecurityContextInformationProvider`, but I can't figure out how to get the PIAB to use that provider and how to get that information into my log file.

I may be missing something obvious, but I can't quite figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say, it looks like there is no way to get the ManagedSecurityContextInformationProvider information into method call logs.  That information is usually logged in extended properties but the LogCallHandler.GetLogEntry method dumps out all of the method parameters and assigns them to the TraceLogEntry ExtendedProperties.

It seems to me that you could either modify the block to add that information or (even better) create your own Custom Call Handler based on LogCallHandler that adds the information that you require.  Either option is not that much work.